# Change Rendered Content DataTable with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm working on a datatable that is modified by a modal dialog.  When the user presses the button labeled "Reconcile" in the "Actions" column of the datatable in the page created by the code below, a dialog box pops up that allows the user to enter a number and press "Reconcile", which replaces the "Reject" and "Reconcile" buttons in that particular row in the Actions column with text telling the user the entered check number.

My view is below:

```
<link href="~/Content/ReconcileStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reconcile";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container-fluid left"><h4 style="float:left;">Reconcile Bank Data</h4><button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#importSettings" style="background:none;"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></button></div>
<div class="container-fluid left">
    <div id="reconcileSection"></div>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <h4>Exceptions</h4>
    <br />
</div>


<div class="container-fluid left">
    <div class="container-fluid left">
        <table id="ReconcileTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover text-nowrap">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-column="CheckNo" class="text-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Check Number" data-container="body">Check No.</th>
                    <th data-column="Exception" class="text-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Exception Reason">Exception</th>
                    <th data-column="IssueDate" class="text-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Date Check was Issued">Issue Date</th>
                    <th data-column="ClearDate" class="text-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Date Check was Cleared">Clear Date</th>
                    <th data-column="ImportDate" class="text-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Date Check was Imported">Import Date</th>
                    <th data-column="Age" class="text-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Age">Age</th>
                    <th data-column="CheckAmount" class="text-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Amount of Check">Check Amount</th>
                    <th data-column="BankAmount" class="text-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Amount Imported from Bank Data File">Bank Amount</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="importSettings" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false" style="height:340px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="z-index:101;">
        <div class="modal-content" style="z-index:101;">
            <div class="modal-header" id="importSettingsHeader" style="background-color:#00A4E5; color:#ffffff; font-size:large;">Import Settings<button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#importSettings" style="text-align:right; background:none; position:relative; float: right; margin-top:-11px;"><i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:black;"></i></button></div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="importSettingsBody">
                <h4>Column Mapping</h4>

                <table>
                    <tr style="margin-bottom: 30px; height:30px;">
                        <td style="width: 210px;">Check Number:</td>
                        <td><input id="importSettingsCheckNumber" type="text" placeholder="ex., A" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="margin-bottom: 30px; height: 30px;">
                        <td>Bank Reference Number:</td>
                        <td><input id="importSettingsBankReferenceNum" type="text" placeholder="ex., B" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="margin-bottom: 30px; height:30px;">
                        <td>Amount:</td>
                        <td><input id="importSettingsAmount" type="text" placeholder="ex., C" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" id="importSettingsFooter"><button class="btn" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#00A4E5;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#importSettings">CANCEL</button><button class="btn" style="background-color:#00A4E5; color:#FFFFFF; margin-left:20px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#importSettings">SAVE</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="verifyBankData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false" style="height:300px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="z-index:101;">
        <div class="modal-content" style="z-index:101;">
            <div class="modal-header" id="verifyBankDataHeader" style="background-color:#00A4E5; color:#ffffff; font-size:large;">Verify Bank Data<button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reconcileDuplicateCheck" style="text-align:right; background:none; position:relative; float: right; margin-top:-11px;"><i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:black;"></i></button></div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="verifyBankDataBody">
                <p>Is the imported information correct?</p>
                <table id="bankDataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover text-nowrap">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-column="CheckNum" class="text-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Check Number" data-container="body">Check</th>
                            <th data-column="BankRef" class="text-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Bank Reference" data-container="body">Bank Reference</th>
                            <th data-column="Amount" class="text-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Amount of Check" data-container="body">Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" id="verifyBankDataFooter"><button class="btn" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#00A4E5;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reconcileDuplicateCheck">NO</button><button class="btn" style="background-color:#00A4E5; color:#FFFFFF; margin-left:20px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reconcileDuplicateCheck">YES</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="reconcileDuplicateCheck" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false" style="height:300px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="z-index:101;">
        <div class="modal-content" style="z-index:101;">
            <div class="modal-header" id="reconcileDuplicateCheckHeader" style="background-color:#00A4E5; color:#ffffff; font-size:large;">Reconcile Duplicate Check<button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reconcileDuplicateCheck" style="text-align:right; background:none; position:relative; float: right; margin-top:-11px;"><i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:black;"></i></button></div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="reconcileDuplicateCheckBody">
                <table>
                    <tr style="margin-bottom: 30px; height:30px;">
                        <td style="width: 210px;">Correct Check Number:</td>
                        <td><input id="reconcileDuplicateCorrectCheckNumber" type="text" placeholder="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" id="reconcileDuplicateCheckFooter"><button class="btn" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#00A4E5;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reconcileDuplicateCheck">CANCEL</button><button class="btn" id="reconcileBtn" style="background-color:#00A4E5; color:#FFFFFF; margin-left:20px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reconcileDuplicateCheck">RECONCILE</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dataTables")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
            'pagingType': 'full_numbers',
            'pageLength': 10,
            'language': {
                'paginate': {
                    'first': '&laquo;',
                    'last': '&raquo;',
                    'previous': '&lsaquo;',
                    'next': '&rsaquo;'
                },
                'info': 'Displaying _START_-_END_ of _TOTAL_',
                'infoEmpty': 'Displaying 0 to 0 of 0',
                'infoFiltered': '',
                'search': '',
                'zeroRecords': 'No matching records found'
            },
            //'dom': '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"<"pull-left"l><"pull-right"i>p<"clear">>',
            'dom': '<"top">rt<"bottom"<"pull-left"l><"pull-right"i>p<"clear">>',
            'initComplete': function (settings, json) {
                $('.dataTables_filter input[type=search]').attr('placeholder', 'Search');
            }
        });

        $(function () {
            var data = $('#ReconcileTable').dataTable({
                'ajax': {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Reconcile")',
                    //data: function(d) {
                    //}
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: 'CheckNo',
                        sortable: true,
                        className: "text-center"
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'Exception',
                        sortable: true,
                        className: "text-center"
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'IssueDate',
                        sortable: true,
                        className: "text-center"
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'ClearDate',
                        sortable: true,
                        className: "text-center"
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'ImportDate',
                        sortable: true,
                        className: "text-center"
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'Age',
                        sortable: true,
                        className: "text-center"
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'CheckAmount',
                        sortable: true,
                        className: "text-center"
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'BankAmount',
                        sortable: true,
                        className: "text-center"
                    },
                    {
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            if (row.Exception == "Dollar/Amount") {
                                return '<div style="text-align: right;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i> RECONCILE</button></div>';
                            }
                            else if (row.Exception == "Missing") {
                                return '<div style="text-align: right;"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="MissingInput" placeholder="Correct Check No." style="width: 150px; margin-right: 10px; position: relative; float: left;" /><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 10px; position: relative; float: right;"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i> RECONCILE</button></div>';
                            }
                            else if (row.Exception == "Duplicate") {
                                return '<div style="text-align: right;"><button type="button" id="rejectBtn" class="btn btn-danger" style="position: relative; margin-right: 10px;"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> REJECT</button><button id="reconcileTableBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="position: relative; margin-left: 10px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reconcileDuplicateCheck"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i> RECONCILE</button></div>';
                            }
                            else {
                                return '';
                            }
                        },
                        sortable: false
                    }
                ],
                sort: true,
                ordering: true,
                order: [0, 'StartDate'],
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true
            });
            var state = "Initial";
            $(document).ready(function () {
                state = "Initial";
                $('#reconcileSection').empty();
                $('#reconcileSection').append($("<button class='btn btn-primary' id='uploadButton'><i class='fa fa-upload'></i> UPLOAD</button>"));
                $(document).on("click", "#uploadButton", function () {
                    $('#reconcileSection').empty();
                    $('#reconcileSection').append($("<table><tr><td><input type='file' id='uploadFile' style='height: 42px; vertical-align: bottom;'></td><td><button class='btn btn-primary' id='reconcileButton' style='margin-left: 30px;'><i class='fa fa-check-circle-o'></i> RECONCILE</button></td></tr></table>"));
                })
                var exceptionsFound = true;
                var count = 0;
                $(document).on("click", "#reconcileButton", function () {
                    state = "Completion";
                    $('#reconcileSection').empty();
                    if (exceptionsFound) {
                        $('#reconcileSection').append($("<table><tr id='success' class='bg-success alert-success' style='margin-bottom: 30px;'><td style='padding-left: 30px; width: 430px;' id='successClose'><i class='fa fa-check-circle-o'></i> Reconciliation complete!</td><td><button id='successClose' class='btn' style='background: none;'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></button></td></tr><tr id='padding' style='background-color: white; height: 30px;'></tr><tr id='exceptions' class='bg-danger alert-danger'><td style='width:430px; padding-left: 30px;'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> Exceptions found. Please reconcile them manually.</td><td><button class='btn' style='background: none;' id='exceptionsClose'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></button></td></tr></table>"));
                        count = 3;
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#reconcileSection').append($("<table><tr id='success'><td><i class='fa fa-check-circle-o'></i> Reconciliation complete!</td><td><button class='btn' style='background: none;' id='successClose'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></button></td></tr></table>"));
                        count = 1;
                    }
                });

                var tableCell;
                var text;
                var newCheckNo;
                $(document).on("click", "#reconcileTableBtn", function () {
                    tableCell = $(this).closest('td').index();
                });

                $(document).on("click", "#reconcileBtn", function () {
                    newCheckNo = $('#reconcileDuplicateCorrectCheckNumber').val();
                    alert(newCheckNo);5
                    tableCell.data("<i class='fa fa-check'></i> Reconciled as Check <strong style='text-decoration: underline;'>$(newCheckNo)</strong>").draw();
                });

                $(document).on("click", "#successClose", function () {
                    if (count == 3) {
                        $('#success').remove();
                        count--;
                    }
                    else if(count == 2) {
                        count = 0;
                        $('#reconcileSection').empty();
                        $('#reconcileSection').append($("<button class='btn btn-primary' id='uploadButton'><i class='fa fa-upload'></i> UPLOAD</button>"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count--;
                        $('#reconcileSection').empty();
                        $('#reconcileSection').append($("<button class='btn btn-primary' id='uploadButton'><i class='fa fa-upload'></i> UPLOAD</button>"));
                    }
                });

                $(document).on("click", "#exceptionsClose", function () {
                    if (count == 3) {
                        $('#exceptions').remove();
                        count--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count = 0;
                        $('#reconcileSection').append($("<button class='btn btn-primary' id='uploadButton'><i class='fa fa-upload'></i> UPLOAD</button>"));
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

So my question is, how do I make this happen?  I'm having issues figuring out how to make the datatable cell value change when the button is clicked (I know it would be in the function:

```
$(document).on("click", "#reconcileBtn", function () {
                        newCheckNo = $('#reconcileDuplicateCorrectCheckNumber').val();
                        alert(newCheckNo);5
                        tableCell.data("<i class='fa fa-check'></i> Reconciled as Check <strong style='text-decoration: underline;'>$(newCheckNo)</strong>").draw();
                    });
```

But I don't know what the code should be on the row that currently starts with "tableCell.data", other than that it's not supposed to be tableCell.data!

Thanks for your help!